# .click function in following code does not seem to work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
echo "<div id = 'div".$video_id."'>";
        echo "<a href = 'videoviewer/index.php?".'video='." " . $bettervidid ."'> <img width='320' height='240' src='thumbnail_uploads/". $image_id."' </img> </a>";
        echo "<button  id = '".$video_id."' value ='".$video_id."'>delete</button>";

        echo $video_id;
        echo "<script>";
            echo '$("#'.$video_id.'").click(function(){';
            echo 'alert("worked")';
            echo '})';
        echo "</script>";

   echo "</div>";
```

For some reason the .click function doesn't work (no alert). I do have jquery on my real code however it is not the problem here.

Comment: why you combined with php code with javascript, use snippet

Comment: I combined php and the other languages because $video_id is a value that comes from a db and I have to loop out the code multiple times.

Comment: try `.on('click', function () ....` instead of click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
<div id = "div<?php echo $video_id; ?>">
    <a href = "videoviewer/index.php?video=<?php echo $bettervidid; ?>"> 
        <img width="320" height="240" src="thumbnail_uploads/<?php echo $image_id ?>" />
    </a>
</div>
<script>
    var video_id = "<?php echo $video_id; ?>";
    $(document).on('#div'+video_id).click(fuction(){
        alert(1111);
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks this works. I'm still confused ony why my way didn't work.

Comment: There are lots of string concatenations in your code so due that your code was not working and also you forgot to include "div" in the Id

Comment: No, I did not forgot to include "div" in my id. In my code, there was a button which had an id that was just the variable $video_id. That was the button I was trying to use for the .click function on. I didn't want to perform a .click function of the div.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnSave").click(
            function () {
                AlertSave();
            }            
        );
    });

function AlertSave() {
   alert("Alert Message OnClick");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnSave">Save Click</button>
```

Comment: for some reason this doesnt work either (ignoring the script tag)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be the script. The problem was  `echo "<div id = 'div".$video_id."'>";`

It should be  `echo "<div id = '".$video_id."'>";`

```
echo "<div id = '".$video_id."'>";
        echo "<a href = 'videoviewer/index.php?".'video='." " . $bettervidid ."'> <img width='320' height='240' src='thumbnail_uploads/". $image_id."' </img> </a>";
        echo "<button  id = '".$video_id."' value ='".$video_id."'>delete</button>";

        echo $video_id;
        echo "<script>";
            echo '$("#'.$video_id.'").click(function(){';
            echo 'alert("worked")';
            echo '})';
        echo "</script>";

   echo "</div>";
```

Comment: The word 'div' shouldnt cause any problems.

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
add jquery library it will be excute. @thespeciamone.

Comment: i already added jquery. If there was an issue an error would pop up.